# How to display certain elements of a list as sticky elements without adding any hierarchy in rendering?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, list, sticky

I have a [chat view](https://bo76x.csb.app/) in which I want the date separators (`Date 1`, `Date 2`,...) to fix to the top edge of the box as the user scrolls through the messages [like this](https://w94qg.csb.app/) without adding any hierarchy in rendering or grouping in data. How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like a `sticky-top` class from Bootstrap help?

Documentation reference:

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/position/#sticky-top

```
Position an element at the top of the viewport, from edge to edge, but only after you scroll past it.
```

Comment: I'm afraid `sticky-top` will have the same drawback as `sticky` and might not solve the cause